# Nodejs dateformat module reference

Tags: node.js

Where `dateformat` module is located and where I can find it's [api docs](https://nodejs.org/api/)?

I see there is a package in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) with name `dateformat`, but on my machine dateformat module is already installed. I'm unable to find it in nodejs official docs.

A'm I missing a whole branch of available modules in nodejs?

Looking forward for some explanation.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option #1 - [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) Documentation

Well Node.js JavaScript, so you can just use the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation.

### Option #2 - Additional Functionality

However the functions included within the Date API, is limited, which is why, as you mentioned, you may want to use an external library. A common, and very stable well supported choice would be [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)